# Start IIS Express without opening default site

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

When I launch my MVC4 project from Visual Studio 2012, IIS Express starts and then automatically launches the default page for the default site (i.e. the one I'm working on).

How do I prevent it from opening the default page - is there a config option somwhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open a different file in your browser when you start then right-click on a file in your Solution Explorer and choose "Set as start page".

To not do anything (i.e. just start IIS without invoking your browser) then go to your project properties and go to the Web tab. There are some settings there.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it: Project -> ProjectName Properties -> Web -> Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application.