# Launch IIS express from Visual Studio without launching the browser or debugger

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Before anyone closes this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063428/start-iis-express-without-opening-default-site), note that the question is NOT asking how to start IIS express by pressing F5 and not launching a browser... I am aware of how to do that.

What I'm asking instead is how to start the IIS express server for the current project without pressing F5 OR rightclicking the solution explorer and selecting "View in Browser".

The scenario is this:

1. I open my web project, and right-click the project and select "View in Browser". IIS Express launches the site and I'm a happy camper.
2. IIS Express for some reason or another is closed, but my browser is still open with the website.
3. I want to start IIS Express again so I can continue where I left off in the existing browser, but there is no option to do so. I have to either "view in browser" again and close the new window, or press f5 to start the debugger, which exits IIS express when it I stop it.

So, in this case, is it possible to simply "start" the IIS express server for the current project WITHOUT manually launching a page OR starting the debugger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start IIS Express Manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300755/how-to-start-iis-express-manually)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be not what you want but it works for me.

Set the property 'don't open a page' in the project properties > web.

I run my project with ctrl + F5
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df5x06h3(v=vs.110).aspx

Refresh my browser or go to page you want.

if you want to skip the ctrl + F5 you can use automatic build software;

Or
http://continuoustests.com/index.html

Comment: i dont know why I didn't think of this. I knew about ctrl-f5 but never connected that to this. durrrrr thanks for posting, this is definitely the answer I was looking for (just needmake sure you have the web selected as the startup project, maybe that's what I was missing before...)!